# Algorithm for parsing (poorly formatted) list of attributes

Tags: python

I know I've seen a good algorithm for this, but having trouble finding it.

I've got a (poorly formatted) output from a tool (whose output style I cannot control) that I need to parse.

It looks something like this:

```
NameOfItemA
attribute1 = values1
attribute2 = values2
...
attributen = valuesn
NameOfItemB
attribute1 = values1
attribute2 = values2
...
attributen = valuesn
```

Where NameOfItemX and  attributeX is a clearly defined set of known names.  Need to turn it into reasonable objects:

```
ObjectForA.attribute1 = values1
```

etc.

I know I've done this before, just cant remember how I did it.  It looked something like:

```
for line in textinput:
    if line.find("NameOfItem"):
        ... parse until next one ...
```

Hopefully what I'm saying makes sense and someone can help

Comment: Do the attribute lines always have the `'='` character in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about:

```
class obj(object): pass
items={}
for line in textinput:
    if(line.find("NameOfItem")!=-1):
       current_object=items[line.replace("NameOfItem","")]=obj()
    else:
       attr,val=line.split('=',1)
       setattr(current_object,attr.strip(),val.strip())
```

Of course, you could ommit the basic object if you already have a class you want to use...
After all is said and done, you have a dictionary of objects with keys=object_names and values = attributes (as strings -- You'll need to convert to whatever type it is supposed to be if it's not a string)

Also note that this input file format looks *A LOT* like that of the `ConfigParser` module.  You could probably read the file and change the `"NameOfItem"` lines to `[item]` lines and pass that to ConfigParser as a StringIO object...

Comment: `if(line.find("NameOfItem"))` does not end with a colon and the logic is off because `find` returns an integer.  You probably want `if 'NameOfItem' in line:` or `if line.startswith('NameOfItem'):`.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for.  Point well taken on the value stripping, class creation etc.  I have all then handled, just was having a brain fart on the algorithm.

I played with ConfigParser, but it doesn't quite meet my needs, mostly because my input data wasn't exactly as I described above (i simplified it to simplify the question), but a good pointer.

Many thanks!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  Yeah, I would use the `if 'NameOfItem' in line:` too, but since he used the other in his example, I went with that.  (and I fixed the missing ':')

Comment: @mgilson: At least fix the logic and add a colon at the end!  `if line.find("NameOfItem") != -1:`.  As written, if `'NameOfItem'` is found at index 0, it will evaluate to `False`'.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I just looked up the find method (I don't use it myself) and had fixed that too -- apparently while you were typing your comment.  The bigger problem was that the line will evaluate to True if 'NameOfItem' isn't in the string.  Whoops.  Some reason I was thinking `find` returned 0 if it didn't find something.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to mgilson's answer, except it places the data in a nested dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
itemname = None
d = defaultdict(dict)
for line in data:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if '=' in line:
        attr, value = line.split('=',1)
        d[itemname][attr] = value
    else:
        itemname = line
```

Answer (score 1):

What about having it as a nested dict:

```
x = {'NameOfItemA': {'attribute1': 'value1', 'attribute2': 'value2'},...}
```

Then you could reference the values as:

```
value2 = x['NameOfItemA']['attribute2']
```

And, supposing the attribute, values always follow a headline such as `NameOfItemN`:

```
items = {}
for line in textinput:
    if line.find("NameOfItem"):
        headline = line
        inner_dict = {}
        items[headline] = inner_dict
    else:
        attr, val = line.split('=',1)
        items[headline][attr] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pyparsing solution you might be interested in. I've added comments to pretty much walk through the code.

```
data = """\
NameOfItemA
attribute1 = values1A
attribute2 = values2A
attributen = valuesnA
NameOfItemB
attribute1 = values1B
attribute2 = values2B
attributen = valuesnB
"""

from pyparsing import Suppress, Word, alphas, alphanums, \
              empty, restOfLine, Dict, OneOrMore, Group

# define some basic elements - suppress the '=' sign because, while
# it is important during the parsing process, it is not an interesting part
# of the results
EQ = Suppress('=')
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums)

# an attribute definition is an identifier, and equals, and whatever is left
# on the line; the empty advances over whitespace so lstrip()'ing the
# values is not necessary
attrDef = ident + EQ + empty + restOfLine

# define a section as a lone ident, followed by one or more attribute 
# definitions (using Dict will allow us to access attributes by name after 
# parsing)
section = ident + Dict(OneOrMore(Group(attrDef)))

# overall grammar is defined as a series of sections - again using Dict to
# give us attribute-name access to each section's attributes
sections = Dict(OneOrMore(Group(section)))

# parse the string, which gives back a pyparsing ParseResults
s = sections.parseString(data)

# get data using dotted attribute notation
print s.NameOfItemA.attribute2

# or access data like it was a nested dict
print s.keys()
for k in s.keys():
    print s[k].items()
```

Prints:

```
values2A
['NameOfItemB', 'NameOfItemA']
[('attribute2', 'values2B'), ('attribute1', 'values1B'), ('attributen', 'valuesnB')]
[('attribute2', 'values2A'), ('attribute1', 'values1A'), ('attributen', 'valuesnA')]
```